# webOnlyScheduleFrameCallback must be initialized first

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I try to transform my FLutter app on Flutter Web,
So, I transform 
`void main => runApp(Myapp());`
to

```
void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    runApp(MyApp());

}
```

But I run flutter run -d chrome, I have a white page and This error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Exception: webOnlyScheduleFrameCallback must be initialized first.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:196)
    at engine.EngineWindow.new.scheduleFrame (window.dart:724)
    at binding$3.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.scheduleFrame (binding.dart:709)
    at binding$3.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.ensureVisualUpdate (binding.dart:665)
    at object$.PipelineOwner.new.requestVisualUpdate (object.dart:880)
    at view.RenderView.new.scheduleInitialFrame (view.dart:126)
    at binding$3.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.initRenderView (binding.dart:140)
```

Flutter doctor :

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.14.6, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.18362.720], locale fr-FR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m facing the same issue and actually didn’t find any solution for now, but as temporary you can try to open your web app in incognito mode. It helps me for now. Also I’m using `webdev serve —auto refresh` command instead of `flutter run -d chrome`.